# An interesting case of regular family of regular functions.

Tags: combinatorics, mathematical-physics, computational-mathematics, combinatorial-proofs

I found this family of functions denoted by $W_{g,n}(z_1 , z_2, \ldots , z_n)$
which are regular appearances in the variable $a$ but I want to find a proof or argument for why this is happening. If there is a pattern.

Let $y(z) = 2 \frac{sinh^{-1}(z/(2a)^{1/2}}{(z^2 +2a)^{1/2}}$

where $sinh(z)$ is the sine hyperbolic function.

$$ K(z):=\frac{1}{z(y(z) - y(-z))} \rightarrow 1/2\,{\frac {a}{{z}^{2}}}+1/6-{\frac {{z}^{2}}{90\,a}}+{\frac {{z}^{4}
}{378\,{a}^{2}}}-{\frac {23\,{z}^{6}}{28350\,{a}^{3}}}+{\frac {263\,{z
}^{8}}{935550\,{a}^{4}}}-{\frac {133787\,{z}^{10}}{1277025750\,{a}^{5}
}}+{\frac {157009\,{z}^{12}}{3831077250\,{a}^{6}}}-{\frac {16215071\,{
z}^{14}}{976924698750\,{a}^{7}}}+{\frac {2689453969\,{z}^{16}}{
389792954801250\,{a}^{8}}}+O \left( {z}^{18} \right) 
 $$
The series is given by Taylor expansion of $K(z)$ around $z= 0$. $a$ is indeterminant. One thing we can immediately notice from the expansion is that the coefficient of $z^{2k}$ is of the form $c_k/a^k$ $c_k$ is constant.

Let $W_{0,2}(z_1, z_2): = 1/(z_1 - z_2)^2$

Let's give some examples of how to generate families of functions
$$W_{1,1} = Res_{z =0}\, K(z)\frac{1}{z-z_1} W_{0,2}(z,-z) = 1/24\,{\frac {{{\it z1}}^{2}+3\,a}{{{\it z1}}^{4}}}
 $$
Taking residue at $z =0$ means collecting the $1/z$ ceofficients.
$$W_{0,3}(z_1, z_2 , z_3) = Res_{z =0}\, K(z)\frac{1}{z-z_1} \left(W_{0,2}(z_1,-z)W_{0,2}(z_2,z) + W_{0,2}(z_2,-z)W_{0,2}(z_1,z)\right)= {\frac {a}{{{\it z2}}^{2}{{\it z3}}^{2}{{\it z1}}^{2}}}
$$

$$W_{1,2}(z_1 , z_2) =Res_{z =0}\, K(z)\frac{1}{z-z_1} \left( W_{0,3}(z,-z,z_2) + W_{0,2}(z,z_2)W_{1,1}(-z)+ W_{0,2}(-z,z_2)W_{1,1}(z)\right)= \\ 1/8\,{\frac { \left( 2\,a{{\it z1}}^{2}+5\,{a}^{2} \right) {{\it z2}}^
{4}+ \left( 2\,a{{\it z1}}^{4}+3\,{a}^{2}{{\it z1}}^{2} \right) {{\it 
z2}}^{2}+5\,{a}^{2}{{\it z1}}^{4}}{{{\it z1}}^{6}{{\it z2}}^{6}}}
 $$
So let's define $W_{g,n}(z_1 , z_2, \ldots, z_n)$ in general by taking the residue of $$W_{g_1,n_1}(z,\ldots)W_{g_2 , n_2}(-z,\ldots) + W_{g-1 , n+1}()\tag{*}$$
along with the product $ K(z)\frac{1}{z-z_1}$.
$W_{g_1,n_1}(z_1 , z_2, \ldots, z_{n_1})$ represent meromorphic functions in $n_1$ variables. And the sum is taken over all such possible combinations. And in case of $W_{g-1 , n+1}(z,-z,z_2 \ldots z_n)$. Notice that there is no $z_1$ terms inside (*). And $W_{g,n}(z_1 , z_2, \ldots, z_n)$ are symmetric in all the variable $z_1 , z_2 , \ldots, z_n$.

Also the term involved in the recursive definition of $W_{g,n}()$ might not be be individually regular in a but the sum is regular.

Comment: Is there a general explicit formula for $W$ or does it require (*)  to define it?

Comment: It's like a recursive definition so for each $W_{(g,n)}$ on the LHS the RHS is given by combination of $W_{(g-1 , n+1)}(z, -z, \ldots)$ and $ W_{g_1 , n_1}(z,\ldots) W_{g_1 , n_1}(-z, \ldots)$. All the tuples on the RHS $2g_1 -2 +n_1 < 2g -2 +n$.